# how to find the number of integers between two numbers inclusive that are divisible by any of the two numbers X or Y.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm, inclusion-exclusion

You are given 4 integers X, Y, L, R. You need to find the number of integers between L and R inclusive that is divisible by any of the two numbers X or Y.

How to find the answer without trying all numbers between L and R.

I know we will use the inclusion-exclusion principle but I can't come up with the solution.

Comment: Find the number divisible by $X$.  Find the number divisible by $Y$.  Adjust for any double-counting

Comment: @Henry and if L=4 and R = 10^18+3 (As an example) 
so I need some closed formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define S(n,d) as the set of positive integers up to and including n that are divisible by d. This set has size n/d (rounded down).

The set of integers divisible by X or Y is the union of two such sets. This is where subtracting the intersection comes in, to avoid double counting, giving a set S(n, X or Y) of numbers divisible by X or Y.

To deal with a range take a difference:
S(R, X or Y) - S(L-1, X or Y)

Comment: the formula will be:
$$(R/X) - ((L-1)/X) + (R/Y) - ((L-1)/Y) - ( R/LCM(X, Y) - (L-1)/LCM(X, Y) )$$

$LCM$ stands for Least Common Multiplier